# Replace a binary file within another binary file

Tags: sed, data-recovery, gzip, binary

Is it possible replace in place a binary file located inside another binary file?
For example, compressed firmware.bin file contains:

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
392           0x188           uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x15075729, created: 1969-12-31 23:59:59, image size: 1572736 bytes, Data Address: 0x20008000, Entry Point: 0x20008000, data CRC: 0x1DCD72E0, OS: Linux, CPU: ARM, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: none, image name: "abcd_rom_bin"
13596         0x351C          gzip compressed data, maximum compression, from Unix, last modified: 2017-08-02 06:04:47
1573192       0x180148        uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x6FFB9B98, created: 1969-12-31 23:59:59, image size: 8376320 bytes, Data Address: 0x0, Entry Point: 0x0, data CRC: 0xC95886CF, OS: Linux, CPU: ARM, image type: Filesystem Image, compression type: none, image name: "abcd_rom_bin"
1573256       0x180188        Squashfs filesystem, little endian, non-standard signature, version 3.1, size: 8372772 bytes, 1028 inodes, blocksize: 131072 bytes, created: 2017-08-02 06:39:51
```

One of these binaries contains also busybox binary,  is there way to replace it without the full decompression?

Comment: Can you make your question clearer.

Comment: It will depend on the file format.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to write the contents of `file.gz` at offset 13596 within `firmware.bin` (overwriting what's already there), you'd do:

### `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/system
{ sysseek -u1 13596 && cat; } < file.gz 1<> firmware.bin
```

### `ksh93`:

```
cat < file.gz 1<> firmware.bin >#((13596))
```

### `dd`, any shell, but reading and writing one byte at a time

```
dd conv=notrunc bs=1 seek=13596 if=file.gz of=firmware.bin
```

### GNU `dd`, any shell, more efficient

```
dd bs=64k conv=notrunc oflag=seek_bytes seek=13596 if=file.gz of=firmware.bin
```

Or to pad with zeros to the length of 1573192 - 13596 (POSIX sh syntax for the arithmetic expansion):

```
dd bs=64k conv=notrunc,sync bs="$((1573192 - 13596))" count=1 \
   oflag=seek_bytes seek=13596 if=file.gz of=firmware.bin
```

Now you'll need `file.gz` to be at most as large as the `gzip`ped file that was already in there. And if those *headers* contain checksums of the different parts, then you'll also need to compute and update the checksums.